# Why does .NET recommend EventHandler's arguments to be derived from EventArgs?

Tags: c#, .net, events

I can possibly understand that having `EventHandler<T>` is convenient, because you don't need to define new delegates all the time and can't understand why its argument should derive from `EventArgs` in .NET. Why are both of these should be used? Is there some additional benefit?

Comment: Also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/11/18/whyeventargs.aspx

Comment: It is not a requirement, just declare your own delegate type.  Do expect somebody to say "huh?" and be sure to help him out by explaining why it was important to you.

Comment: @HansPassant: It's a requirement in .NET, but not in C# in general.

Comment: No, it is not a requirement in either.

Comment: From MSDN: "Although the C# language allows events to use any delegate type, the .NET Framework has some stricter guidelines on the delegate types that should be used for events". Maybe I read it wrong, but sounds like a requirement to me.

Comment: guidelines != requirements

Comment: @p.s.w.g. Hmm... i was actually confused by "should"... but again it's not "must". I will change the question.

Comment: @dsolimano: Agree, it's a duplicate, although the chosen answer on the other question is not trivial to understand. Deanna's answer is better. Also thanks for the link to Krzysztof's blog.

Comment: It is indeed IMO, and now it's the highest voted.